# Terraform lambda function with archive_file

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following terraform code which executes via Infrastructure/Lambda/main.tf - the Infrastructure folder is the root module of my project:

```
// Create lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "scheduled_lambda" {
  function_name = "test-schedule-lambda"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_scheduler.arn
  runtime       = var.runtime
  filename      = "${path.root}/Lambda/test.zip"
  handler       = "index.lambda_handler"
  // Ensures archive is created prior to the lambda function
  depends_on = [
    data.archive_file.zip_the_python_code
  ]
}

// Create archive file to be used in lambda function
data "archive_file" "zip_the_python_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.root}/Lambda/scripts"
  output_path = "${path.root}/Lambda/test.zip"
}
```

When I am trying to run my `apply` stage from my pipeline, I receive the following error:

```
unable to load "./Lambda/test.zip": open ./Lambda/test.zip: no such file or directory
with module.potentium_lambdas.aws_lambda_function.scheduled_lambda,
on Lambda/main.tf line 153, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "scheduled_lambda":
```

So it is complaining about the `aws_lambda_function.scheduled_lambda resource` and the file I provided to it. I dont understand this as the `output_path` on the data resource (which did not fail) is the exact same as the lambda function `filename` parameter. FYI, full tree of the project below:

```
├── Backup
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── Containers
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── Databases
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── Lambda
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── test.py
│   └── variables.tf
├── Networks
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── Security
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── Storage
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── terraform.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Try using `path.module` instead of `path.root`

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED because first answer was not enough]

The resource you create should be dependent on the data outcome. So, you can try to use the data output in a resource the lambda is dependent on:

```
// Create archive file to be used in lambda function
data "archive_file" "zip_the_python_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.root}/Lambda/scripts"
  output_path = "${path.root}/Lambda/test.zip"
}
// Ugly wrapper - temporary resource
resource "local_file" "lambda" {
  source = data.archive_file.zip_the_python_code.output_path
  filename = "${path.root}/local_lambda_zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "scheduled_lambda" {
  [...]
  filename = local_file.lambda.filename
  [...]
}
```

Comment: This results in the exact same error as what I put in my post unfortunately.

Comment: I have edited the answer, maybe this helps

Comment: Also, what Terraform version you use?